# JSON error I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character

Tags: java, android, json, spring

I develop an Android app that communicates with a back-end developed with Spring. Sometimes, when I send a POST request with Retrofit, the back-end throw this error: ERROR RestExceptionHandler:29 - org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x616d6765 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #4, byte #19).

Searching about this, I've logged the JSON sent in Retrofit onResponse callback and noticed it was not complete. It's something like that:

```
{
"key": "value"
"arrayKey": [
    {
        "objectKey": "objectValue"
    }
]
"key2": "value2",
"key3": "
```

It just stop the JSON creation.

I don't know if this happens because of my convertion to JSON function when I log, or if the object creation has some error. And more strange, when users send multiple times, in one moment everything happens alright.

This is the function to convert object into JSON that I use to log the sent object in Retrofit:

```
public static <T> String ToJson(T obj) {
    try{
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.v("convertion_error", ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't think the problem is in the log function, because almost everytime the log is OK, with the complete JSON.

This is my object creation function:

```
private CreatedObject objectCreation(Parameter parameter) {
    CreatedObject createdObject = new CreatedObject();
    createdObject.setInformation1(parameter.getInformation1());
    createdObject.setInformation2(parameter.getInformation2());
    createdObject.setInformation3(parameter.getInformation3());
    createdObject.setDate(DateFormatHelper.getGMTDate());
    List<ObjectArray> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataObject p : parameter.getData()) {
        ObjectArray ob = new ObjectArray();
        ob.setInformation5(p.getInformation5());
        ob.setInformation6(p.getInformation6());
        ob.setInformation7(p.getInformation7());

        objects.add(ob);
    }
    createdObject.setArrayInformations(objects);
    return createdObject;
}
```

Someone already got this incomplete JSON error using Retrofit?

Comment: Is the JSON exactly the one which is outputted by Gson?

Comment: Yes @LppEdd. Just changed the names of keys and values. It just stops in the middle a few times.

Comment: So the problem is inside your Android app? At the line "gson.toJson(obj);" ?